# What is the math symbol ~ with ind over it?

Tags: statistics, notation, noise

The symbol I'm talking about is from a statistics article here:

[image]

Comment: "ind" probably stands for "independent" but without more context it is hard to be sure exactly what they are claiming is independent.  The $\sim$ symbol usually means "has distribution", i.e. $X \sim N(0,1)$ means $X$ has a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.